# How do I plot a trace of an object's path in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Question #1a. [5 points] Suppose that an ant wandered randomly by taking steps (x,y), one per second, where at each ant step, x and y come from a normal distribution with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.0mm (assume this for all questions below). Plot a trace of the ant’s path over the course of an hour.

```
mean = 0
sd = 1.0
side = np.random.normal()
step = np.random.normal()

for side, step in np.random.normal(1,3600): #3600 seconds in one hour
    side += 1
    step += 1
    x.append(side) #one step in x direction
    y.append(step) #one step in y direction

plt.plot(x,y,color = "darkpink")
```

Comment: Do you want us to solve your homework  for you?

Comment: No. I obviously included my code for a reason. I'm fairly new at coding, and with this code I get an error message. Any debugging or tips on how to make it more Python-friendly would be appreciated. I understand the concepts behind the question, but my syntax is a little off. Professor lectures on neuroscience/psychology, but leaves us to figure out coding without any formal resources.

Comment: Please include the mentioned error message in the question and describe with which parts of the syntax you have problems with. Furthermore, have a look at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question on SO :)

Comment: Here is a link to the image of the error. Thank you

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HQOj.png

Comment: The error is due to the fact that you are trying to loop over a float which is a non-iterable. There are other problems in that line which i try to explain in my answer

Answer (score 1):

There are sever problem with the code you posted,

- You are actually not creating an array of shape (1,3600) but a single float which gives you the error in the for loop. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) of `np.random.normal` you will see that the first two positional arguments are for the *mean* and for the *standard deviation*. The 3rd parameter is actually the shape, which you can access as a keyword argument.
- Even if you were getting a (1,3600) array, in your for loop you would be expanding a (1,3600) array on 2 variable which is not possible as the expansion happens along the first axis
- I'm not sure why you are summing one to *side* and *step* since if you would be getting the right value `norm(0,1)` you would jsut be shifting the mean from 0 to 1 `norm(1,1)`.
- The append inserts an element inside a list, but in no place you are considering that the path after step(n) should be the sum of the path at step(n-1) plus step(n).

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path = steps = np.random.normal(size=(3600,2))

# pos(n) = pos(n-1) + step(n)
for n in range(path.shape[0]-1):
    path[n+1] += path[n]

# Compact way to plot x and y: (3600,2) -> (2,3600) and the * expand along the first axis
plt.plot(*path.T)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]